# Conditional types and injecting interface?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Been having issues with typescript and conditional types with generics. My usecase is that I want to have a class which utilizes generics. The class can either take an object, or an array.

If it takes in an array type, the objects in the array must have additional fields, depending on the interface. if it's just an object, then it will allow the object to stay the same. What I've tried so far is:

```
// Goal:
// Allow either of 2 scenarios:

// 1) A generic object with any properties - must not be an array.
// 2) An array of objects. The objects inside the array must contain a property called uuid of type string.

// Problem:
// type "object" is too broad, allowing for an array to "fallback"
// if it does not have the required uuid property.

interface IStorageObject {
    uuid: string;
}

type Unarray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : T;
type StorageObject<T> = Unarray<T> & IStorageObject;

// We tried: Manager<T extends object | Array<StorageObject<T>>>
export class Manager<T extends Array<StorageObject<T>>> {
    public data: T;

    constructor(data: T) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

// Test with Object
// We wish to allow objects with any properties

interface ITestObject {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
}
// We have no requirement in properties ↓
const managerForObject = new Manager<ITestObject>({
    property1: "123",
    property2: 123,
});

// Test with Array
// Objects inside array MUST have uuid property

interface ITestObject {
    property1: string;
    property2: number;
}

// We have uuid property requirement for the object ↓
const managerForArray = new Manager<Array<ITestObject>>([
    {
        property1: "123",
        property2: 123,
    },
]);

// Main problem:
// This is not an error ↓
const test: object = [];
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-kdqapm?file=index.ts

Incase you want to have a go at it, I made a playground with the code inside.

Thanks in advance, and I hope the link will provide further info about the issue.